# Failed to call "SignUp.php" page functions defined in Action in PHP form?

Tags: php, yii, form-submit

I am novice in PHP and trying to make register form onclick of submit button i have used action which will process the user's enter details means username length and password length but this function is not being called onclick of submit button **my browser is showing me whole code whatever i have written in "SignUp.php" page**.Can someone pls help me......
   **InternHtml.php code**

```
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapperClass">
   <fieldset>
            <legend class="regLagendClass">Registration Form</legend>
    <form id="registrationForm" method="POST" action="SignUp.php">
           <!-- <form id="registrationForm" method="get" action="">-->
            <div class="divClass">
                <label for="firstName" class="labelClass">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text"  name="fName" class="textboxClass" id="firstName" placeholder="Your First Name"/>
            </div>

            <div class="divClass">
                <label for="lastName" class="labelClass">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="lName" id="lastName" class="textboxClass" placeholder="Your Last Name"/>
            </div>
 <div class="divClass">
                <label for="userName" class="labelClass">User Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="textboxClass" placeholder="Your User Name" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="divClass">
                <label for="password" class="labelClass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="textboxClass" placeholder="Type Password" required/>
            </div>
 <div class="divClass">
                <label for="cPassword" class="labelClass">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="cPassword" name="userPassword" class="textboxClass" placeholder="Retype Password"/>
            </div>

            <div class="divClass">
                <label for="gender" class="labelClass">Choose Gender:</label>
                <select name="gender" class="textboxClass">
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="divClass">
                <label class="labelClass" for="dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                <input type="date" id="dob" class="textboxClass" placeholder="Your Date of Birth"/>
            </div>
            <div class="divClass">
               <!-- <label for="country" class="labelClass">Country:</label>
                <input type="text"  id="country" class="textboxClass"/>-->
                <label for="emailId" class="labelClass">Email Id:</label>
                <input type="email"  id="emailId" name="userEmail" class="textboxClass"/>
            </div>

            <div class="divClass">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
            </div>
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

**SignUp.php Code**

```
 function registerFunction()
{
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $uname = $_POST['userName'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];
   $errorMessage;
    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);
    $uLength = strlen($uname);
    $pLength = strlen($pword);
    if($uLength >= 0 && $uLength <= 10)
    {
    $errorMessage = "UserName Length";
    }
    else
    {$errorMessage = "No error in UserName Length";
    }
    if($pLength >= 0 && $pLength <= 10)
    {
    $errorMessage = "password Length";
    }
    else
    {$errorMessage = "No error in password Length";
    }
    if(strlen($errorMessage) == "")
    {
    echo "There is no error::::NO Error Message" .$errorMessage;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "There is error::::Error Message" .$errorMessage;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you are not calling function registerFucntion() at all, just remove this function and its scope, and place your code <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ......... } ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not at all calling your `registerFunction()` anywhere ..

Just rewrite your SignUp.php like this

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $uname = $_POST['userName'];
    $pword = $_POST['password'];
    $errorMessage;
    $uname = htmlspecialchars($uname);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);
    $uLength = strlen($uname);
    $pLength = strlen($pword);
    if($uLength >= 0 && $uLength <= 10)
    {
        $errorMessage = "UserName Length";
    }
    else
    {$errorMessage = "No error in UserName Length";
    }
    if($pLength >= 0 && $pLength <= 10)
    {
        $errorMessage = "password Length";
    }
    else
    {$errorMessage = "No error in password Length";
    }
    if(strlen($errorMessage) == "")
    {
        echo "There is no error::::NO Error Message" .$errorMessage;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is error::::Error Message" .$errorMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: when i am trying to call function then whole page is just displaying in browser means whole page code whatever is written

Comment: That is because you have not added the `<?php` tag on your code and also you are not calling this `registerFunction()` anywhere . Did you try the code I had given you ?

Comment: i have added <?php tag and now using Netbeans but still its showing me code

Comment: Seems like you have not configured PHP properly. Just create some file `test.php` and add this `<?php phpinfo();` and try running it.

Comment: yes still on writing phpinfo() i am getting whole page code in brwser instead of functions functionality

Comment: Do you have some sort of software to run your code, Netbeans is just an IDE. You may need something like apache to run your code.

Comment: @user3233280, How are testing your URL ? It should be like `http://localhost/test.php`

Comment: i am getting error The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server.   when trying to write this what u told

Comment: You need to copy all your files inside the `www` folder of your wamp installation directory and should test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `registerFunction()` function **SignUp.php**